# Can't add Facebook account to messages in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, facebook-chat, windows-8-messaging-app

Every time I try to link my Facebook account so that I can use the Windows 8 messaging app, it shows me this:

[image]

It has now been over 24 hours, and Facebook has been working fine the whole time, so I'm not convinced it's an issue on their end.

Comment: Try sniffing outbound connections and see what message the FB auth server returns.

Comment: Are you able to add any other type of account? The problem may not be specific to Facebook.

Comment: There's no other type of account to choose in the messaging app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now, I guess it was a temporary problem.